# Why final variable incrDecr is not available inside onPressed() function

Tags: flutter

After running the code Error:Undefined name incrDecr.
I am trying to update weight(which is a global variable) by incrementing it in a custom widget(RoundIconButton).

```
class RoundIconButton extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  RoundIconButton(this.icon,this.incrDecr);
  final IconData icon;
  final bool incrDecr;

  @override
  _RoundIconButtonState createState() => _RoundIconButtonState();
}

class _RoundIconButtonState extends State<RoundIconButton> {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: RawMaterialButton(
        onPressed:(){
          if(incrDecr==true)    //undefined name incrDecr
          weight++;
        } ,
        elevation: 6,
        shape: CircleBorder(),
        fillColor: Color(0xFF4C4F5E),
        constraints: BoxConstraints.tightFor(
          width: 56.0,
          height: 56.0,
        ),
        child: Icon(widget.icon),     //but icon is working fine 
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have statefull widget you have to access your parameters with `widget` the same way as you access your icon

```
widget.incrDecr
```